# How to create a new Tenant using OKTA

Tags: single-sign-on, okta, okta-api

I am new to OKTA and have created an OKTA developers account to test my application. Now, I am attempting to create a new Tenant in the OKTA admin console so that each of my applications can have a separate Tenant Application.

I plan to use SSO architecture and integrate OKTA with the respective applications. However, I am encountering issues creating a new Tenant in my OKTA admin console.

If anyone knows answer for this, please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Okta's Workforce or Customer Identity Cloud? Workforce is at developer.okta.com, and Customer Identity is Auth0. If you're using Auth0, you can create multiple tenants for one account. If you're using Okta, you have to create separate accounts to have multiple tenants.